# Linux serial port buffer not empty when opening device

Tags: linux, serial-port, pyserial

I have a system where I am seeing strange behavior with the serial ports that I don't expect. I've previously seen this on occasion with usb-to-serial adapters, but now I'm seeing it on native serial ports as well, with much greater frequency.

The system is set up to run automated tests and will first perform some tasks that cause a large amount of data to be outputted from the serial device while I do not have the ports open. The device will also reset itself. Only the tx/rx lines are connected. There is no flow control.

After these tasks complete, the testware opens the serial ports and immediately fails because it gets unexpected responses. When I reproduce this, I found that if I open the serial port in a terminal program, I see several kilobytes of old data (that appears to have been sent when the port was closed) immediately flushed out. Once I close this program, I can then run the tests as expected.

What could cause this to happen? How does Linux handle buffering the serial port when the device is closed? If I opened a device, made it send output, and then closed it without reading from it, would this cause the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux terminal driver buffers input even if it is not opened.  This can be a useful feature, especially if the speed/parity/etc. are set appropriately.

To replicate the behavior of lesser operating systems, read all pending input from the port as soon as it is open:

```
...
int fd = open ("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
if (fd < 0)
        exit (1);

set_blocking (fd, 0);   // disable reads blocked when no input ready

char buf [10000];
int n;
do {
        n = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf);
} while (n > 0);

set_blocking (fd, 1);  // enable read blocking (if desired)

...  // now there is no pending input



void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block)
{
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
                error ("error %d getting term settings set_blocking", errno);
                return;
        }

        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = should_block ? 5 : 0; // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
                error ("error setting term %sblocking", should_block ? "" : "no");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case. So, why do I only see this behavior part of the time? I'm using pyserial for test, and the included miniterm.py script as an interactive terminal. It's not just one serial port that has the problem. It seems to alternate. All the serials ports will have data incoming when they are closed, but only one will end up with it buffered at the point when I open it. Perhaps the baud rate is only being left set correctly on that one?

Comment: @djs:  Port speed is the first thing that comes to mind for me.  It could also be that `gpsd` or `logind` is accessing closed ports looking for a GPS device or login connection and changes the port speed speculatively.

Comment: Neither of those services are running. stty reported all the ports at 115200 right before I checked and found only one of them kept the buffer. Is this the right tool to use to check the baudrate?

Comment: @djs:  `stty -F /dev/ttyWhatever` is what I have always used and never had a problem.

Comment: @djs:  did you get things running smoothly?

Comment: I still have no good explanation why I don't normally see this behavior on serial ports. I've adjusted the test framework to clear the buffer at start, which solves the problem, if not my curiosity...