# open linux serial port w/o flushing buffered bytes

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have an application where an external device is always transmitting bytes (non ASCII data) to my Linux ARM Cortex board via serial port/dev/ttyO1, 115200,N,8,1.

After Linux boot, my user-space C program is to open the serial port and begin reading data immediately (**including** any already buffered data).
Ideally, the kernel would initialize the serial port as early as possible and then buffer incoming bytes until my program gets started.

Currently, when my C program gets started, the open() appears to "flush" any buffered bytes.  Code will look something like this -- with a bit more error handling :) :

```
// no need to set UART parameters, that's been done for us earlier
//
unsigned sfd = open("/dev/ttyO1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

while (1)
{
    uint8_t buffer[120];

    int nbytes = read(sfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if(nbytes > 0)
    {
        buffer[nbytes] = 0;
        printf("[%s]", buffer);
    }
}
```

1. is there a way to prevent open() from flushing the receive buffer?
2. what mechanism can initialize /dev/ttyO1 the earliest and have it
   buffer received bytes?

To be clear I want */dev/tty* to buffer incoming bytes while linux is booting.

Comment: Related: [Linux serial port buffer not empty when opening device](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8084818/103167)

Comment: i do not recall linux "buffering" data in hope that someone will open a serial connection on that port and read that data. The serial port on Linux is a file descriptor like in many other devices there. As long as the FD is not used( aka no device or software is using the fd resource) there is no reason for the kernel to bother buffering the data.